# Assigning mySQL AS results to variable

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to assing the `AS` variables in my mySQL statement to variables so I can process the results. However I am unable to assign the to these vairables.

mySQL `SELECT` statement is as follows

```
$sql = "SELECT min(ups) AS minups, max(ups) AS maxups, min(downs) AS mindowns, max(downs) AS maxdowns, min(score) AS minscore, max(score) AS maxscore, min(comments) AS mincomments, max(comments) AS maxcomments, min(totalVotes) AS mintotalvotes, max(totalVotes) AS maxtotalvotes FROM reddit WHERE movie = ':movie'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindValue( ":movie", $redditMovies->reddit, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
```

I am trying to assign them to these variables

```
$minups = $row ['minups'];
$maxups = $row ['maxups'];
$rups = (int)($maxups - $minups);
print_r($rups);
$mindowns = $row ['mindowns'];
$maxdowns = $row ['maxdowns'];
$rdowns = (int)($maxdowns - $mindowns);
$minscore = $row ['minscore'];
$maxscore = $row ['maxscore'];
$rscore = (int)($maxscore - $minscore);
$mincomments = $row ['mincomments'];
$maxcomments = $row ['maxcomments'];
$rcomments = (int)($maxcomments - $mincomments);
$mintotalvotes = $row ['mintotalvotes'];
$maxtotalvotes = $row ['maxtotalvotes'];
$rtotalvotes = (int)($maxtotalvotes - $mintotalvotes);
```

What do I need to change to resolve this problem?

Comment: And what happens next?? What error are you getting?? What you mean by unable to assign the to these vairables.??

Comment: What is the actual problem you having? Did you check error log?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned there is no error at all. Nothing is returned

Comment: You don't need the 'AS' words. That's mostly for subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing parenthesis in your query like,

```
movie = ':movie' to movie = :movie
```

Comment: where should that go? what does it do? Could you add some more detail to your answer?

Comment: @Default It will help user to debug & after that on his reply help us to get his problem solve. A only start based on the information provide by the user in question.

Comment: The return is an array of NULL values. The query itself work fine when I manually assign the `WHERE =` so I guess it must be problem with how I am assigning the `:movie bindValue`

Comment: check output of `var_dump( $stmt->bindValue( ":movie", $redditMovies->reddit, PDO::PARAM_INT ));` should be `bool(true)`

Comment: returned value `bool(true)`

Comment: when I `var_dump($redditMovies->reddit)` all the values are present and correct. Although when I `print_r($redditMovies->reddit)` none of the values are separated. Could this suggest something?

Comment: One more go try to bind your result like in this [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#example-1759) & check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26949/discussion-between-rikesh-and-user1711576)

Answer (score 1):

USe this code. use **`extract($row)`** is used for **directly assign the value for the key's** in a **$row** array

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT min(ups) AS minups, max(ups) AS maxups, min(downs) AS mindowns, max(downs) AS maxdowns, min(score) AS minscore, max(score) AS maxscore, min(comments) AS mincomments, max(comments) AS maxcomments, min(totalVotes) AS mintotalvotes, max(totalVotes) AS maxtotalvotes FROM reddit WHERE movie = ':movie'");
    $stmt->bindValue( ":movie", $redditMovies->reddit, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    extract($row);
    echo $minups;  // it prints the minups value from the result set $row.

    $rups = (int)($maxups - $minups);
    $rdowns = (int)($maxdowns - $mindowns);
    $rscore = (int)($maxscore - $minscore);
    $rcomments = (int)($maxcomments - $mincomments);
    $rtotalvotes = (int)($maxtotalvotes - $mintotalvotes);
```

this extract($row); is used for assign the value for the key's

example:

```
$row['maxups']=5;
$row['minups']=2;
extract($row);   
echo $maxups."-".$minups;
```

output: 5-2

Comment: Thank you for your help. However I now think the problem lies in the way the variable is being assigned in the `WHERE = ` statement

Comment: is query return the value? use the code to print_r($row); give me the array output..

Comment: the return in the array for each variable is NULL

Comment: echo "SELECT min(ups) AS minups, max(ups) AS maxups, min(downs) AS mindowns, max(downs) AS maxdowns, min(score) AS minscore, max(score) AS maxscore, min(comments) AS mincomments, max(comments) AS maxcomments, min(totalVotes) AS mintotalvotes, max(totalVotes) AS maxtotalvotes FROM reddit WHERE movie = '".$redditMovies->reddit."'"; 

run this query in you mysql server. is this return any value from the query browser or not?

Comment: please check your query. it will return the value means definitely works.  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT min(ups) AS minups, max(ups) AS maxups, min(downs) AS mindowns, max(downs) AS maxdowns, min(score) AS minscore, max(score) AS maxscore, min(comments) AS mincomments, max(comments) AS maxcomments, min(totalVotes) AS mintotalvotes, max(totalVotes) AS maxtotalvotes FROM reddit WHERE movie = '".$redditMovies->reddit."'");
    $stmt->execute();

Comment: yeah that echoes correctly. The problem appear to have been on the parenthesis around `':movie'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo '<pre>';
 print_r($row);
```

If you are getting no values in the array then check the query whther there is any error

Comment: The query itself work fine when I manually assign the `WHERE = ` so I guess it must be problem with how I am assigning the `:movie bindValue`